# How to get DATE from DATETIME column?

Tags: sql, asp.net, datetime, sql-server-2005

I want to get date from DateTime column.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [book_id], [book_name], [taken_date], [last_date], [renewed_date], [status], [comment], [fine_amount] FROM [library] WHERE ([admn_no] = @admn_no)">
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="admn_no" PropertyName="Text" 
   Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

From the above these 
`[taken_date]`,`[last_date]`,`[renewed_date]` 
columns showing date and time

> (eg: `4/14/2015 12:00:00 AM`).

How do I display only date

> (eg: `4/14/2015`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use     `CAST(column_name AS DATE)` for Sql-server 2008 and above version

```
SELECT [name], [book_id], [book_name], 
cast([taken_date] as date) as [taken_date], 
cast([last_date] as date) as [last_date], 
cast([renewed_date] as date) as [renewed_date], 
[status], [comment], [fine_amount] 
FROM [library] WHERE ([admn_no] = @admn_no)
```

**EDIT 1**

for earlier version before sqlserver 2008 you can do it like

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
```

so the whole query will go like this

```
SELECT [name], [book_id], [book_name], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[taken_date],111) as [taken_date], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[last_date],111) as [last_date], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[renewed_date],111) as [renewed_date], 
[status], [comment], [fine_amount] 
FROM [library] WHERE ([admn_no] = @admn_no)
```

**EDIT 2**

for formatting your date from `yyyy/dd/mm` to `dd/mm/yyyy` you can change to `101` rather than `111`

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)
```

so query will be

```
SELECT [name], [book_id], [book_name], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[taken_date],101) as [taken_date], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[last_date],101) as [last_date], 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[renewed_date],101) as [renewed_date], 
[status], [comment], [fine_amount] 
FROM [library] WHERE ([admn_no] = @admn_no)
```

Comment: while using the above code showing output as " 2015/04/14". I want to display it as "04/14/2015"

Comment: instead of 111 use 101 in CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[last_date],111)